# On reading Allie Brosh's book

Tags: quotes

There is a question/answer paragraph with misty meaning:

> Q:Are mom and dad still alive?
>
> A:Actually, you turned out to be Batman, so we had to have them put
>   down for story-line purposes.

What does the last phrase mean?

Answer (score 5):

The meaning used is the third meaning of [*put down*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/put+down):-

> To subject (an animal) to euthanasia.

The sentence means "we had to dispose of your parents in this way to make your biography fit the Batman story".

Comment: In the Batman story, Batman's parents died when he was young.  They were murdered by the Joker.  "Have you ever danced with the devil in the pale moonlight?"

Comment: By the way, http://english.stackexchange.com/q/31060/14666

Comment: @Lumberjack Ahem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joe_Chill

Comment: @mplungjan I was never a big comic book fan, but I loved the original series with Adam West, and movies always got my attention.  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4F9RzLqKu2g [1:56]   I stand corrected.

Comment: Ah, yeah, the freedom of the screen writers :)