# Starting every item of an enumeration with to

Tags: lists

I am writing a research and I have to describe a process. To do this I have chosen an enumeration as follows:

> 1. To include ...
> 2. To add ...
> 3. To program ...
> 4. To write ...

I am not sure about starting each item of the list with the preposition `to`. I think best practices say that it is the way to do it, but it sounds a bit repetitive for me. Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might write your enumeration like this, whereby the preposition will apply equally to each word in your list, without the need for repeating it: -

> To: -
>
> 1. Add ...,
> 2. Program ...,
> 3. Write ...,

Comment: Thank you! So in my case it could be something like:

... the steps to follow are to:

1. Include ...
2. Add ...

Comment: Yes exactly.  Whether you use a colon, or a colon and a hyphen, is a matter of style, in Britain ':-' is frequently used to introduce lists. See here for example for some more discussion: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/31060/is-it-proper-to-use-a-colon-followed-immediately-by-a-hyphen - but yes, that 'lead in' works fine, it's good grammar to end each list item with a comma also

Comment: Very interesting discussion thread! I am going to follow your styling advice. Just a final question: the last item must finish with a full stop instead of a comma, isn't it?

Comment: @bra_racing Yes the last item should end with a full stop. There is a wealth of styling advice here you might find useful, and it discusses how to end a list and much more also, e.g "Use a period after the last item in the list." - http://www.getitwriteonline.com/archive/101406VerticalLists.htm